# Error: Procedure or function X expects parameter @Username, which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to call a soap webservice using this method. However, when I tap the button for the login service to execute i get the following error:

Server was unable to process request. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'spGetUserByUsername' expects parameter '@Username', which was not supplied.

here's the code involved in services.js:

```
.factory('loginService', ['$soap', function($soap){
var base_url = 'http://localhost/UserService3/WebService1.asmx';

return {
GetUser: function(uname){
    return $soap.post(base_url,"getUserByUsername", { Username: uname});
}
};
```

}])
and here's the code involved in controller.js:

```
$scope.enterlogin = function(usern,pass)
{
   loginService.GetUser(usern).then(function(response)
   {
      console.log('user is = ' + response);
   });
}
```

how do i pass the data?

Update: here's the server-side code involved:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string getUserbyUsername(string uname)
    {
        string cs = "Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = UsersDB; Integrated  Security = True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetUserByUsername", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter(@"Username", uname);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            User user = new User();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                user.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();
                user.Password = reader["Password"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();

            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user); 

        }
    }
```

Comment: That error seems to be referring to your server-side code where you are calling a stored procedure in your database and not supplying the required parameter.

Comment: @Lex hi, i added the server-side code

Comment: Your web service is expecting a parameter named `uname`, but you are sending an object with a parameter of `Username`. I'm guessing if you were to debug the server-side code you're getting a null?

Comment: @Lex, yes i used to get a null. thanks for the clarification. the response is returning undefined though.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not super familiar with `$soap.post` as we use `$http.post` exclusively, but I'm guessing `$soap.post` returns a promise so you will need to implement `.then()`, `.error()` and possibly `.finally()` methods. You should be able to find examples of this pretty easily.

Comment: ok, thanks a bunch.